# What could be causing Windows updates to fail?

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, windows-update, grub2

I have a multi-boot system with Ubuntu 16.04 and two copies of Windows 10. The partition layout is as follows:

```
/dev/sda1, file system = ext4, size = 30.52 GiB, label = Ubuntu 16.04
/dev/sda2, file system = ntfs, size = 64.00 GiB, label = Windows 10 (1)
/dev/sda2, file system = ntfs, size = 64.00 GiB, label = Windows 10 (2)
/dev/sda4, file system = extended, size = rest of drive
```

Every time I attempt to install updates under Windows 10, it fails in the installation process displaying

> "We couldn't complete the updates. Undoing changes. Don't turn off your computer".

I've ran the Windows 10 Troubleshooter, which fails with the error

> "Windows 10 service registration is missing or corrupt".

I tried the fix on the [Microsoft forums](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_update/windows-10-service-registration-is-missing-or/a2bfb3c3-665f-4f22-92d9-cf82f0a950be?auth=1) with no luck.

I brought up Windows 10 using a different drive but on the same machine and I was successfully able to download and install all updates. Using DiscWizard, I imaged that installation and restored it to "Windows 10 (1)" on the first drive and was unable to install updates, receiving the same error.

Could the existence of the Linux partition be confusing Windows? Or possibly Windows doesn't like being booted from Grub 2? I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: Your inability to update Windows has NOTHING to do with Linux also existing on the system.  It also has nothing to do with the fact your using Grub 2 has your bootloader.  Unless you provide specifics about the failures I can't submit an answer that explain how you solve your problem.

Comment: @Ramhound How much more specific do I need to be regarding the failures? I provided what caused the errors, what the error messages were, and what I attempted to do to fix them.

Comment: There is a log file that is generated that has more information you should provide the relevant information from that.

Comment: @Ramhound I generated a log for Windows Update by running the "Get-WindowsUpdateLog command in a powershell cmdlet. I'm not sure what you mean by relevant information but doing a search in the log for "error" provides: "EP: error: 0x800004004 : - failed to get SLS data", "EP: error: 0x80004004: GetSecondaryServicesEnabledState failed"

Comment: Feel free to update your question at any point.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tn55RYEXzbs

Comment: windows doesn't like GRUB boot loaders. Temporary remove GRUP, update Windows and install GRUB again.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix the problem by making the Windows 10 partition active and hiding the Linux partition using a Grub4DOS memory stick. I found that Windows 10 wants to park files wherever the active partition is. In my specific case, the active partition was Ubuntu, and being that Ubuntu requires the EXT4 file system (a file system that Windows doesn't understand), Windows 10 wasn't able to write the files it needed to in order to successfully update.

Although Windows is the active partition, the Grub 2 menu still appears and Windows and Ubuntu both run as they should.

Comment: Thanks! your investigation help me resolve my issue with updating windows 10.

Answer (score -1):

@puzzl3 
I can indeed confirm that when dualbooting windows 10 and ubuntu linux on a BIOS/MBR bootstrap the bigger windows upgrades will always fail/stuck (We Couldn't...loop) if the Ubuntu/Grub2 partition is set to active!

To complete updates you can switchback to windows as active partition (only when its own partition is also bootable) using windows CLI tool "diskpart".

Start>Command Prompt> diskpart "UAC Yes"
    list disk
    sel disk 0
    list part
    sel part x
    active
    exit

You can revert to grub2 as bootloader after the windows upgrades succeeds by setting he Grub2/ubuntu partition back as active again. This may not work if Grub2 is installed in the MBR itself instead of PBR!

Comment: Why the downvote with no comment?